# Flask & SQLAlchemy - Command Line & Shell use correct database connection, but API/Curl does not

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Hive -

I have a Flask + React application that is running on Debian 11 via Nginx and Gunicorn.  In development, everything works great ask it uses SQLAlchemy + SQLite to manage data queries.

In production, my .env file includes the connection details to the PostgreSQL database. After that is when it gets weird (at least for me, but this may be something that people commonly run into that my hours on Google just didn't turn up):

1. When I installed the app on production and set the .env file, I performed the flask db upgrade, and it wrote to the PostgreSQL database (confirmed tables exist).
2. When I ran the command line command to create an admin user in the new environment, it created my user in PostgreSQL on the `users` table with my admin flag.
3. When I go into flask shell I can import db from the app (which is just an instantiation of SQLAlchemy) and import User from the AUTH API.  Once those are imported, I can run User.get.all() and it will return all users from the PostgreSQL table.  I've even ensured there is a unique user in that table by manually creating it in the DB to validate that it doesn't get created in two systems.
4. When I use curl to hit the API to login in, it says that the `users` table is not found and references that it tried to query SQLite.

To summarize, I can not figure out why command line/shell interfaces correctly pull in the PostgreSQL connection but hitting the API falls back to SQLite.  I'm not even sure where to start in debugging...even in the os_env call in the main app that says, "Pull from the env or fall back to development," I made the fall back = production.

All commands are executed in venv.  Gunicorn is running within the same venv, and validated by tailing the logs that supervisor compiles for Gunicorn.

I am happy to provide any code that might be needed, but I am unsure what is and is not relevant.  If it helps, the original base was built off of this boilerplate, and we have just expanded the API calls and models and defined a connection string to PostgreSQL in Production but left the SQLite connection string in development...the operation of the app works exactly the same: https://github.com/a-luna/flask-api-tutorial/tree/part-6

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.

When you launch Gunicorn, it ignores your .env file and any environment variables you may have set in the Shell.  Even when your app specifically loads the .env file, Gunicorn still ignores it.

There are a variety of solutions but, since I was using Supervisor and also had a large number of variables to load, using the --env flag on Gunicorn was not an option.

Instead, add this to your Gunicorn file.  Since I was using a virtualenv and had installed it via pip, my gunicorn command was running from ./project-root/venv/bin/gunicorn.

Modify that file as so:

At the top where your imports are, you will want to add:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

Then, anywhere before you actually load the app (I put mine right after all of the imports), add this block of code where I have two environment files called .env and .flaskenv:

```
for env_file in ('.env', '.flaskenv'):
    env = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), env_file)
    if os.path.exists(env):
        load_dotenv(env)
```